# Quick noob question about variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Stupid question,
but if I have code like this:

```
var x;
var y;
var z = x + y;
```

And then through the program I update the variables for x and y, but when I use the console to check var z, it gives me NaN. So the program is doing that calculation once at the beginning and not updating Z as it continues.  So what's the solution to keep checking Z for the variable changes? Do I have to do a loop with setInterval to keep checking the new updated Z variable? Thanks

Comment: Easiest would be making `z` a function that you could invoke to add `x + y` at any time

Comment: In general, that's a very hard problem. [FRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming) has one answer.

Comment: Can you provide more context on what you are trying to accomplish? If you're code is exactly as you wrote it there then z will always be NaN, because x and y are not initialized before assigning z

Comment: @RStig , You can see below my response to Johnny. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, your comment is right. JavaScript doesn't provide a way to create a live binging.

**So what's the solution to keep checking Z for the variable changes?**

All depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Basically I have a bunch of items on the page that when clicked, add to X and Y.  They are different so that's why I've categorized them as such.  and Z is the total sum of the two categories that now have value from the user's selection

Comment: Ok, so let's say two buttons: x and y, that went clicked they increase by one and z is the sum of them all, and you want to update z every time you update x or y, right?

Answer (score -1):

What you think about the code:

```
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
var z = x + y;
console.log("The value of z variable: ", z);
```

PS. Preferably you should use `let`:

```
let x = 1;
let y = 2;
let z = x + y;
console.log("The value of z variable: ", z);
```